# virtualenvwrapper, add2virtualenv from python script

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenvwrapper

I got a project with files like it:

```
├── main_folder
    ├── my_folder
          ├── my_file.py
    ├── main_file.py
```

Inside `main_file.py` i am trying to run a below command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.getstatusoutput(f'add2virtualenv FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT/main_folder')
```

but as a response i am getting `(127, '/bin/sh: 1: add2virtualenv: not found')`
How can i solve it so i could use inside a `my_file.py` below line:

```
from main_file import something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add2virtualenv` and other virtualenvwrapper's commands are shell **functions** defined in `virtualenvwrapper.sh`; to call them you need first to source `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in the same shell. Also be warned they work with `bash` or `zsh` but not with `/bin/sh`.

So my advice is to create a bash script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
add2virtualenv "$1"
```

and call it as a subprocess:

```
subprocess.getstatusoutput(f'myscript FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT/main_folder')
```

Comment: thank you for your comment :) trying it right now

Comment: So i created myscript inside main_folder so it's the same level as main_file and everything else i copied from you and i get an error: 127, '/bin/sh: 1: myscript: not found')

Comment: If the script is not in the `$PATH` you should call it with absolute or relative path. `subprocess.getstatusoutput(f'./myscript FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT/main_folder')` for example